# AngularJS, Restangular - Setting Restangular.baseUrl on run time

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm using AngularJS and Restangular. How can I define the baseUrl to use on run time? I dont think that I can use run or config methods since is the user the one who selects the server to connect to.

I have this so far:

```
        var rest = Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer){
            RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl(baseUrl);
        });
```

This works fine when using rest to do the calls **BUT** when Im in need of using **Restangular.copy** this **Restangular does not have the baseUrl defined**.

How could I defined the Restangular.baseUrl for the Global/ Singleton one on run time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#configuring-restangular) say:

> You can set all these configurations in RestangularProvider or
>   **Restangular service** to change the global configuration [...]

This means, you are able to inject `Restangular` into your controller, directive, service, ... , and call `Restangular.setBaseUrl(baseUrl)`. I can assure that this works with other configuration methods like `setDefaultHttpFields` too.